# Proving $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=f''(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

The following question can be found in Bartle, Introduction to real analysis as well as Walter Rudin, Principle of Mathematical analysis:

Let $f$ be differentiable function defined on an open interval $I$

Suppose $f''(a)$ exist at $a \in I$

Then $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=f''(a)$

The first approach suggested by the Rudin is applying L'hopital's rule to $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}$ 
This yields $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)+f'(a)-f'(a-h)}{2h}=f''(a)$

And thus proving the statement.

However, I encounter a difficulties when I tried to prove the statement by mean value theorem. Here is my attempt.

By mean value theorem, $\exists c_2 \in (a,a+h)$ such that $f(a+h)-f(a)=hf'(c_2)$.

Similarly, $\exists c_1 \in (a-h,a)$ such that $f(a)-f(a-h)=hf'(c_1)$

Hence $f(a-h)-f(a)=-hf'(c_1)$

Therefore, we have  $\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=\frac{f'(c_2)-f'(c_1)}{h}=\frac{f'(c_2)-f'(a)+f'(a)-f'(c_1)}{h}$

As $f''(a)$ exists,$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ such that $|\frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{h}-f''(a)|<\epsilon$ when $ |x-a|<\delta$

Hence if $|h|<\delta$ then $|c_2-a|<\delta,|c_1-a|<\delta$

and we get $lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(c_2)-f'(a)+f'(a)-f'(c_1)}{h}=2f''(a)$

which is inconsistent with the statement.

Can anyone tell me about what is wrong in my attempt.
Thank you.

Comment: You have a typo in your formula:  You dropped a - sign in the numerator of the fraction in the line that begins with "Therefore."

Comment: How did you deduce that $\frac{f'(c_2)-f'(c_1)}{h}=\frac{f'(c_2)-f'(a)+f'(a)f'(c_1)}{h}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the intermediate point $c_2 \in (a,a+h)$ arising from the MVT we have

$$\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(c_2) - f'(a)}{h} &=  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(c_2) - f'(a)}{c_2 - a} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c_2 - a}{h} \\ &= \lim_{c_2 \to a} \frac{f'(c_2) - f'(a)}{c_2 - a} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c_2 - a}{h} \\ &= f''(a)\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c_2 - a}{h}\end{align}  $$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2176722/148510) for a proof that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c_2 - a}{h} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Similarly we can show,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a) - f'(c_1)}{h} = \frac{1}{2} f''(a)$$

Putting it all together in the approach you are pursuing, you will at arrive at the correct limit:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) -2f(a) - f(a-h)}{h^2} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(c_2) - f'(a)}{h}+\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(a) - f'(c_1)}{h} \\ &= \frac{1}{2}f''(a) + \frac{1}{2} f''(a) \\ &= f''(a)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(c_2)-f'(a)}{h} = f''(a)$$

because $c_2 \neq a+h$.

Comment: As stated "differentiable function  on an open interval" probably means the derivative exists where needed for MVT.  Otherwise this question is a non-starter.

Comment: I guess the derivative *has* to exist on an open interval around $a$ or $f''$ doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @Robert Shore $a<c_2<a+h \implies c_2 = a + \theta h$ for $0<\theta<1.$ So $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {c_2 - a} {h} = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {\theta h} {h} = \theta.$ So $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f'(c_2)-f'(a)} {h} = \theta f''(a) < f''(a).$ Am I right?

Comment: @Dbchatto67: With $c_2 = a + \theta h$ produced by the mean value theorem, the $\theta$ is not generally a constant but also depends on $h$. I gave you a link to my answer that proves $\theta \to 1/2$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Yeah I have seen it. Thanks @RRL for the remark you have made.